# facebook: Is there a documented way to send facebook updates from an external application?

Tags: .net, facebook, mono, desktop-application

Is there an official way for sending facebook updates (i.e. wall texts with links) from a (desktop) application?

Does anyone know an existing .NET library for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's are several Open Source FB client for .NET:

- The [Facebook API for .NET](http://facebook.codeplex.com/) should be able to post updates [and more](http://facebook.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Feature%20List&referringTitle=Home).
- The [Facebook Developer Toolkit for .NET](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) has some [good tutorials like this one](http://www.devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-use-the-facebook-developer-toolkit-20/).

Sadly, I have not used these or any of the other .NET clients, so I can't say which is better. In any case, you should get your start at the [Facebook Developer's page](http://developers.facebook.com/).